# Как закрыть тег в PHP

Tags: php

В содержании на лету добавляется тег HTML `code`:

```
    $tag_pre = array('<pre class="html">',
                     '<pre class="css">',
                     '<pre class="js">',
                     '<pre class="php">'
    );

    $tag_code = array('<pre><code class="html">',
                      '<pre><code class="css">',
                      '<pre><code class="js">',
                      '<pre><code class="php">'
    );

$content = str_replace($tag_pre, $tag_code, $content);
```

Как закрыть тег `code`?

Чтобы было например так:

```
<pre><code class="html">текст</code></pre>
<pre><code class="css">текст</code></pre>
<pre><code class="js">текст</code></pre>
<pre><code class="php">текст</code></pre>
```

Сейчас код в содержании:

```
<pre class="js hljs javascript">JavaScript: object.style.свойство=<span class="string">"значение"</span>flex-basis</pre>
```

Стили `hljs javascript` для тега `pre class="js` добавляет библиотека highlight.pack.js. В ней легко менять добавление стилей для любого тега, но нужно для `code`!

Comment: `$content = str_replace('</pre>', '</code></pre>', $content);`

Comment: Так закроются закрытые теги! Будет два раза `</code></code>` - так не нужно.

Comment: Каким образом они закроются, если их у вас не было? И вы добавили только открывающиеся.

Comment: Сделать регулярками или функциями с перебором массива. Иначе вы не сможете отслеживать конец тега.

Comment: Не знаю каким образом получается, но результат такой `<pre class="box">текст</code></pre>`

Comment: Раз замена охватывает не все теги `pre` значит `str_replace()` вам не подойдет. Нужен инструмент для работы с DOM.

Comment: пишите регулярку для `<pre class="(html|css|js|php)">(.*?)</pre>` с заменой на `<pre><code class="$1">$2</code></pre>`

Comment: Так? `$content = preg_replace('~<pre class="(html|css|js|php)">(.*)</pre>~', '<pre><code class="$1">$2</code></pre>', $content);`

Comment: @Viher, хотелось бы, чтобы вы добавили в вопрос, часть скрипт-кода -  которая приходит в `$content`.

Comment: код в переменной $tag_pre

Comment: @Viher если стили добавляет библиотека js, то это выполняется уже после пхп. Приведите пример исходных данных, который имеется на входе в пхп.

Comment: на выходе `<pre><code class="js hljs javascript">текст</pre>`

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно закрыть все открытые теги:

```
function closetags($html) {
    preg_match_all('#<([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
    $openedtags = $result[1];
    preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);
    $closedtags = $result[1];
    $len_opened = count($openedtags);
    if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {
        return $html;
    }
    $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {
        if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)) {
            $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
        } else {
            unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

[Источник](https://gist.github.com/JayWood/348752b568ecd63ae5ce)

Comment: Не сразу заметил, что вопросу уже целый год исполнился.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вы можете использовать регулярные выражения и [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php).

Пример:

```
$html = <<< HTML
    line1
    <pre>pre w/o class</pre>
    line 3 <pre class="js">pre class js</pre>
    line 4
    <pre class="php">pre class php</pre>  
HTML;

$html = preg_replace(
            '/<pre class="(php|js|html)">(.*?)<\/pre>/',
            '<pre><code class="$1">$2</code></pre>',
            $html);

print_r($html);
```

получим

```
line1
<pre>pre w/o class</pre>
line 3 <pre><code class="js">pre class js</code></pre>
line 4
<pre><code class="php">pre class php</code></pre>
```

Comment: Что то не то. У меня работает только для одного класса js.

Comment: @Viher Добавьте тестовый пример исходного текста в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил, если что нужно добавить, спрашивайте.